# Induced Topology In Irreducible Subset

Tags: general-topology

If T is a topological space, and X an irreducible subset of T, is it true that every open subset U of X, under the induced topology, is dense in X? I know the result is true for U open in T and contained in X, but does it hold under the induced topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The property of being irreducible is intrinsic to the topological space in question, i.e. it does not depend on some ambient space $T$ containing $X$. It is also the case that every nonempty open subset of an irreducible topological space is dense in that space. So you can see, the space $T$ is completely irrelevant to your question.